# Proxies and Python Requests Library Wont Change IP

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, proxies

I am trying to archive a site via scraping (API is not an option), and am using proxies to bypass the rate limit on the site.

I am using the python requests library, and using a list of proxies stored in `proxies.txt`, which contain working proxies

I am using a class called ProxyManager to handle rotating proxies and verifying them
ProxyManager.py

```py
class ProxyManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._proxie_data = []
        self._verified_proxies = []
        self._current_proxy_index = 0
        with open('./proxies.txt', "r") as file:
            self._verified_proxies = file.read().strip().split("\n")

        self._filter_proxies(debug=True)

    def _filter_proxies(self, debug=False) -> None:
        new_proxies = []
        total_proxies = len(self._proxie_data)

        if debug:
            for proxy in self._proxie_data:
                new_proxies.append({'http': proxy})
                self._verified_proxies = new_proxies

            self._current_proxy_index = random.randint(0, len(self._verified_proxies) - 1)
            return    

    def get_current_proxy(self):
        self._current_proxy_index += 1

        if self._current_proxy_index >= len(self._verified_proxies) - 1:
            self._current_proxy_index = 0

        return self._verified_proxies[self._current_proxy_index]
```

When doing either of the following:

```py
class Content:
    def __init__():
        proxy_manager = ProxyManager()
        self.sess = requests.Session()
        self.sess.get(url, headers=self.headers, proxies=proxy_manager.get_current_proxy())
```

or

```py
class Content:
    def __init__():
        proxy_manager = ProxyManager()
        self.sess = requests.Session()
        self.sess.proxies.update(proxy_manager.get_current_proxy())
```

My IP address stays the same as my own global IP address, and wont change to the ip address of the proxy. Other similar questions yield the same result

Comment: Where does `self.sess` come from?

Comment: Part of a class, self.sess is a requests session